# Setup Facebook Real-Time Updates for User Deactivated / Deauthorized App

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

I'm trying to set up Facebook's Real-time Updates with my Google App Engine application and I was able to get a real-time update registered for User -> Friends field, but I would also like to know when a user deactivates their account or deauthorizes my application (ie. the 'installed' field). Is there a default real-time update that is sent to any endpoint registered to User? or how can I detect that a user has left my application?

Thanks,

Evan

Comment: That’s what the Deauthorize Callback URL is for (you set it in the “Advanced” settings tab in your app dashboard) – it gets a `signed_request` parameter POSTed that contains info about the user that deauthorized your app. See also f.e. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/379/facebook-deauthorize-callback-url-and-its-response-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings your app on facebook, click the "advanced" tab

In there is a setting for

"Deauthorize Callback URL:"

This url is pinged when a user deauths your app. I'm not sure how "realtime" it is, but I assume it's pretty quick

I'm not 100% sure on the parameters passed to this, so you might have to create a page that logs the $_REQUEST somewhere so you can inspect, but I know the users UID is in there somewhere. Then you can perform whatever clean-up you need to